# Node.js as gateway

Tags: node.js, rest, websocket, gateway, mqtt

I am thinking of using node.js as a gateway. I want to implement several frontends (browser, apps etc.) which get served by node.js with data over websockets. Node.js cannot fetch this data directly from a database but node.js should get it from a backend through an interface which makes it easy to replace the backend. So I was thinking of using a restful layer or a publish /subscribe protocol like MQTT as interface. 
Ok ... question: Is this a good idea? Can node.js act as a gateway and what modules do you recommend for such a purpose?
[image]

Comment: Did you get that project to work? I'm looking for similar solution but I have no idea where to start (examples, tutorials etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a good idea?

I'd think of it this way. **Yes**, this is a use case well-suited to node.js's strengths.

> what modules do you recommend for such a purpose?

- app server: express.js
- web sockets: socket.io (maybe socks.js)
- HTTP from gateway to back end: hyperrequest or superagent or request.js
- if you need any straight-up HTTP proxy functionality: node-proxy

Comment: how about mqtt? I found MQTT.js by adamvr on github.

Comment: I haven't personally tackled that use case or used any libraries in that space, so I can't make any recommendations. In general, finding good modules isn't hard, though. Just search npm/google and try them out.

Comment: And there is no Problem with using express, websocket server and backend interface in one node instance? Are there no performance worries or something like that?